# I have defined the variable but python still shows error

Tags: python, variables, nameerror

This progam was working fine before i used data validation(the while loops) but now i get the following error -
average_grade = (grade1 + grade2) / 2
NameError: name 'grade2' is not defined
This error was not happening before , I have just started programming so i am quite confused

```
 valid = False
    while valid==False:
        grade1 = float( input("Enter the grade1: ") )
        if grade1 <0  or grade1 > 10:
            print('Please enter a grade between 0 and 10')
            continue
        else:
            valid = True
    
    while valid==False:
        grade2 = float(input("Enter the grade2: "))
        if grade2 < 0 or grade2 > 10:
            print('Please enter a grade between 0 and 10')
            continue
        else:
            valid = True
    
    while valid == False:
        absences = int(input("Enter the number of absences: "))
        if type(absences)!=int:
            print("Number of absences can only be an integer value")
            continue
        else:
            valid = True
    while valid == False:
        total_classes = int(input("Enter the total number of classes: "))
        if type(total_classes)!=int:
            print("Total number of  classes can only be an integer value")
            continue
        else:
            valid = True
    
    
    
    average_grade = (grade1 + grade2) / 2
    attendance = ((total_classes - absences) / total_classes)*100
    
    print(average_grade)
    print("Your attendance is :", attendance , "%")
    
    if(average_grade>=6):
      if(attendance>=0.8):
          print("YOU HAVE PASSED")
      else:
        print("You have failed as your attendance is less than 80%")
    elif(attendance>=0.8):
        print("You have failed due to average grade being lower than 6")
    else:
        print("You have failed due to average grade being lower than 6 and attendance lower than 80%")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never resetting the value of `valid`, so once you set `valid = True` in the first `while` loop, none of the other loops will execute (because the loop condition will be false).

You don't need the `valid` variable in any case; instead of having a
conditional loop expression with a flag, just `break` out of the loop
when you receive a valid value:

```
while True:
    grade1 = float( input("Enter the grade1: ") )
    if grade1 <0  or grade1 > 10:
        print('Please enter a grade between 0 and 10')
        continue
    else:
        break

while True:
    grade2 = float(input("Enter the grade2: "))
    if grade2 < 0 or grade2 > 10:
        print('Please enter a grade between 0 and 10')
        continue
    else:
        break

while True:
    absences = int(input("Enter the number of absences: "))
    if type(absences)!=int:
        print("Number of absences can only be an integer value")
        continue
    else:
        break

while True:
    total_classes = int(input("Enter the total number of classes: "))
    if type(total_classes)!=int:
        print("Total number of  classes can only be an integer value")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but when you have a boolean variable you
don't need to compare it explicitly to `False` (or `True`); you can
use the value of the variable itself as the condition:

```
while somevar == False:
```

You can just write:

```
while not somevar:
```